# django template "<" changed to '&lt;'

Tags: python, django

in the views. I have a str

```
str = "<div class='rprtnum nohighlight'>"
```

I pass str to a template. When I load the template, it doesn't display correctly. I looked at the source of the html, it shows

```
&lt;div class=&quot;rprtnum nohighlight&quot;&gt;
```

How do I keep <, >, " in the str in the html page?  I tried html.escape(str), it didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `escape` filter.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!  It works now.